# Multiplying or adding constants within $P(X \leq x)$?

Tags: probability

Is it always true, that, for a positive constant $c$, we have $P(X \leq x) = P(c X \leq cx)$ for some continuous random variable $X$?

Further is it always true that $P(X + c \leq x + c) = P(X \leq x)$?

If so, what governs the equality?

Answer (score 5):

When you write $P(X \leq x)$, hidden in the background (if you haven't learned measure-theoretic probability) is the following:

- $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a [real-valued random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Real-valued_random_variables).
- $P$ is a [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure#Definition).

The actual meaning of $P(X \leq x)$ is:
$$P(X \leq x) = P(\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)\leq x\})\text{.}$$
This is regardless of whether $X$ is a continuous or discrete random variable.

The following facts are necessary to show that your equalities are true:

- **Fact**. If $X$ is a random variable, so is $Y = X + c$ for some constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
- **Fact**. If $X$ is a random variable, so is $Z = cX$ for some constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Hence, we may see that
$$\begin{align}
P(Y \leq x + c) &= P(\{\omega: Y(\omega) \leq x + c\}) \\
&= P(\{\omega: (X + c)(\omega) \leq x + c\}) \\
&= P(\{\omega: X(\omega) +c\leq x + c\})
\end{align}$$
which is clearly equal to $P(X \leq x)$.

One may show similarly for $P(Z \leq cx)$ for some $c > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

You can do all those things.

$X \le x$ is an event in your probability space. To put it less formally: for each of your possible outcomes, you have an associated value of $X$, and $X \le x$ is the event (set of outcomes) corresponding to values of $X$ that are less than $x$.

If we change $X \le x$ to $cX \le cx$ (for $c> 0$) or $X+c \le x+c$ or anything that describes the same values of $X$, we have a different description of the same event. There are no outcomes which make $X\le x$ occur but don't make $cX \le cx$ occur, or vice versa. So its probability will be the same.

We can always do anything to the inside of $\Pr[X \le x]$ that we could do *and* undo to an inequality. We are looking for the two-way implication $X \le x \iff X+c \le x+c$. As long as that holds, we're good.

Often, we can actually do *more* manipulations with the inside of a probability, that are only valid because of our specific experiment. For example, if we flip lots of coins, and $X$ is the number that land heads, then $X \le 2.5$ and $X \le 2$ are different descriptions of the same event. Even though they are not equivalent statements, there are no outcomes for which one event occurs, and the other does not.

Comment: "We can always do anything to the inside of $Pr[X \leq x]$ that we could do and undo to an inequality." This is my takeaway. I've been manipulating inequalities within a probability just like how I manipulate inequalities in algebra. I've always just assumed it's valid, but never really looked into what justifies it from a probabilistic standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to both questions is yes. I'll come at this from a standpoint of not knowing anything about measure theory. For the first question, note that the area under the graph of a PDF must be $1.$ So we ask ourselves, what does the graph of the PDF of $2X$ look like compared to the graph of $X$? Well, it is spread out more by a factor of two in the $x$-direction. But if we left is at that, then the area under the PDF for $2X$ would be $2$. Therefore, we must make the following adjustment: if the PDF for the random variable $X$ is $f(x)$ with domain $a\leq x \leq b,\ $ then the PDF for the random variable $\ 2X\ $ is $\frac{1}{2}f\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)$ with domain $\ 2a\leq x \leq 2b.\ $ But $2$ was arbitrary here, and so we get the following more general result:

> if the PDF for the random variable $X$ is $f(x)$ with domain
> $-\infty\leq a\leq x \leq b\leq \infty,\ $  then for $c>0,\ $ the PDF
> for the random variable $\ cX\ $ is
> $\frac{1}{c}f\left(\frac{1}{c}x\right)$ with domain $\ ca\leq x \leq cb.\ $

The diagram below demonstrates for $c=2$.
$$$$
[image]

The area of the two green rectangles is the same: the area of the rectangle in $\frac{1}{2}f\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right),$ is twice as short and twice as fat as it's corresponding rectangle on the $f(x)$ diagram. Thus "Area = $1$" has been preserved.

Since area is the limit of the sum of rectangles, these "approximate rectangles" can be formalised by the Lebesgue/measure theory. In fact, this is probably the purpose of Lebesgue/measure theory: to formalise this integration stuff.

Now, going back to your original question, which was:

> is $P(X \leq x_0) = P(c X \leq cx_0)$ always true?

If we use some less technical results (than measure theory) like the fundamental theorem of calculus with the reverse chain rule, we can see that:

$$P(X \leq x_0) = \int_a^{x_0} f(x) dx = F(x_0) - F(a),$$

and

$$ P(c X \leq cx_0) = \int_{ca}^{cx_0} \frac{1}{c}f\left(\frac{1}{c}x\right)dx = \left[\frac{1}{c}\times cF\left(\frac{1}{c}x\right)\right]_{ca}^{cx_0} = F(x_0) - F(a), $$

attaining the required result.

A similar way of thinking about shifting of graphs can be done to attain the affirmative result for the second question.

Comment: Or maybe this line of reasoning is completely incorrect? If you add two Bimodal normal distributions, $X$, each with peaks at $-1$ and $1$, then $X+X$ will be a trimodal distribution with peaks at $-2, 0, $ and $2$. So this answer is wrong then?

Comment: What's a "bimodal normal distribution"? (Also, the distribution of $2X$ is not the same as the distribution of the sum of two *independent* copies of $X$.)

Comment: Like a Normal Distribution but with two peaks instead of one. See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution Also, are you sure that is true? I thought $2X$ and $X+X$ were the same (although I’m not certain)?

Comment: $2X$ and $X+X$ are the same, but $X+X$ is not the same as adding together two independent copies of $X$. Consider a simple distribution which is $0$ or $1$ with equal probability. If $X$ has this distribution, then both $X+X$ and $2X$ will be $0$ or $2$ with equal probability. But if $X_1, X_2$ have this distribution, then $X_1 + X_2$ will be $0, 1, 2$ with probabilities $\frac14, \frac12, \frac14$ respectively.